# Need to obtain Awk output in specific sequence

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

Data in file:

```
1234567-5678907
3456789-1234563
3456789-1234567
.
.
.
.
n
```

Now I want the output in the below format:

```
1234567-5678907,3456789-1234563,3456789-1234563....n
```

I have used below command but I am getting an extra comma in starting:

```
awk -F"-" ' {printf ",%s-%s",$1,$1} END{print""}'
```

Please share the command that can be used in a shell script.

Comment: If you don't *need* to use awk: `paste -s -d, file`

Comment: With `printf`: `awk 'NR==1{printf "%s", $0};NR>1{printf ",%s", $0};END{print ""}'`

Answer (score 3):

Using Awk's output record separator, [ORS](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=",";}1' infile
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. This awk solution is lacking a final line terminator, and instead has a spurious `,`. (See Glenn's solution that is clean in those respects.)

Comment: @Janis Spurious? I prefer to think of it as vestigial... :)

Answer (score 3):

There's already a solution based on `paste` in the comment above. But if you prefer `awk`, here's an `awk`-solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";OFS=","};$1=$1'
```

It doesn't create a spurious comma at the end and properly terminates the output by a newline.